# Creating a LinkedList containing unique wordnodes of a text source

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to create a `LinkedList` of nodes containing unique words of a text and for each node create another list containing the words that follow them in the text.
I have come up with this code, but it is not correct. It seems that method `contains` always produces `false`. Any suggestions?

```
public void train(String sourceText){
    String[] words=sourceText.split("\\s+");
    List<String> textList=Arrays.asList(words);
    starter=textList.get(0);
    System.out.println(starter);
    ListNode prevWord= new ListNode(starter);
    wordList = new LinkedList<ListNode>();
    wordList.add(prevWord);
    for (int i=1;i<textList.size();i++){
        if (wordList.contains(prevWord)){
            prevWord.addNextWord(textList.get(i));
        }
        else{
            wordList.add(prevWord);
            prevWord.addNextWord(textList.get(i));
            }
        prevWord=new ListNode(textList.get(i));
    }
}

class ListNode
{
    private String word;

    private List<String> nextWords;

    ListNode(String word)
    {
        this.word = word;
        nextWords = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public void addNextWord(String nextWord)
    {
        nextWords.add(nextWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Could you provide an example text an what the end state of your list should look like.

Comment: Please post some sample output or error.

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems good,but i haven't tested yet. I will this afternoon and i'll provide you feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly found out `wordList.contains(prevWord)` always returns false - that is because java checks for object equality meaning that the objects are the *same* - not look the same, but actually *are* the exact same object.

But beyond that I think you were on a good track - I still changed your code quite a bit but you might able to see some aspects that remained from your attempt:

```
public void train(String sourceText){
    String[] words = sourceText.split("\\s+");

    LinkedList<ListNode> wordList = new LinkedList<>();
    outerLoop: for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (ListNode node : wordList) {
            if (node.getWord().equals(words[i])) {
                if (i != words.length - 1) {
                    node.addNextWord(words[i+1]);
                }
                continue outerLoop;
            }
        }

        ListNode node = new ListNode(words[i]);
        wordList.add(node);
        if (i != words.length - 1) {
            node.addNextWord(words[i+1]);
        }            
    }

    System.out.println(wordList.size());
}
```

Let me explain what this code does:

- it splits the words (as you did)
- it creates an empty list of `ListNode`s
- it loops over the words

  - it looks for any already existing `ListNode` in the list that has the the same `word`
  - if one is found the word after the current word is added to the `ListNodes`'s `nextWords` list
  - if no matching node is found the code reaches the second part of the loop where I create a new node
- that node is added to the list of nodes and maybe gets a next word added

That code is not perfect, has duplication and uses a labels and continues, but you can get rid of them pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally works.Thank you all for your help and especially Luk.Your code has a null pointer exception due to wordlist being empty when entered the for node loop.

```
public void train(String sourceText){
        String[] words=sourceText.split("\\s+");
        //List<String> textList=Arrays.asList(words);
        starter=words[0];
        ListNode prevWord= new ListNode(starter);
        wordList = new LinkedList<>();
        wordList.add(prevWord);
        outerLoop: for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for (ListNode node : wordList) {
                if (node.getWord().equals(words[i])) {
                    if (i != words.length - 1) {
                        node.addNextWord(words[i+1]);
                    }
                    continue outerLoop;
                }
            }

        ListNode node = new ListNode(words[i]);
        wordList.add(node);
        if (i != words.length - 1) {
            node.addNextWord(words[i+1]);
        }            
    }

    System.out.println(wordList.size());
}
```

Comment: The normal procedure is to add the minor change to *my* answer and upvote + accept that answer rather than posting a minimal different answer of your own - additionally there is no NPE in my code from what I could see and test. Having an empty list in the beginning is absolutely no problem.

Comment: i am really sorry, i am totally new in stackoverflow, but i certainly upvoted your answer (where is accept? ok found it). There was no problem with your code but this was part of a bigger problem so in mine editio there was an npe, that's why i changed it and posted. Really sorry luk and thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, I upvoted your question - you now have earned the privilege  to upvote answer yourself